# How to stop Spark Structured Streaming from filling HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, amazon-emr, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark Structured Streaming task running on AWS EMR that is essentially a join of two input streams over a one minute time window. The input streams have a 1 minute watermark. I don't do any aggregation. I write results to S3 "by hand" with a `forEachBatch` and a `foreachPartition` per Batch that converts the data to string and writes to S3.

I would like to run this for a long time, i.e. "forever", but unfortunately Spark slowly fills up HDFS storage on my cluster and eventually dies because of this.

There seem to be two types of data that accumulate. Logs in `/var` and `.delta`, `.snapshot` files in `/mnt/tmp/.../`. They don't get deleted when I kill the task with CTRL+C (or in case of using `yarn` with a `yarn application kill`) either, I have to manually delete them.

I run my task with `spark-submit`. I tried adding

```
--conf spark.streaming.ui.retainedBatches=100 \
--conf spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown=true \
--conf spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints=true \
--conf spark.cleaner.periodicGC.interval=15min \
--conf spark.rdd.compress=true
```

without effect. When I add `--master yarn` the paths where the temporary files are stored change a bit, but the problem of them accumulating over time persists. Adding a `--deploy-mode cluster` seems to make the problem worse as more data seems to be written.

I used to have a `Trigger.ProcessingTime("15 seconds)` in my code, but removed it as I read that Spark might fail to clean up after itself if the trigger time is too short compared to the compute time. This seems to have helped a bit, HDFS fills up slower, but temporary files are still piling up.

If I don't join the two streams, but just `select` on both and `union` the results to write them to S3 the accumulation of cruft int `/mnt/tmp` doesn't happen. Could it be that my cluster is too small for the input data?

I would like to understand why Spark is writing these temp files, and how to limit the space they consume. I would also like to know how to limit the amount of space consumed by logs.

Answer (score 0):

Spark fills HDFS with logs because of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22783

One needs to set `spark.eventLog.enabled=false` so that no logs are created.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @adrianN's answer, on the EMR side, they retain application logs on HDFS - see https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/core-node-emr-cluster-disk-space/